# Set size of subplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I wonder how to set the size of the subplot when figure contains multiple subplots (5 × 2 in my case). No matter how big I allow the whole figure to be, the subplots always seem to be small. I would like to have direct control of the size of the subplot in this figure. The simplified version of the code is pasted below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randn(20)
y = np.random.randn(20)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))

for i in range(0,10):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(5, 2, i+1)
    plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
    ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
    # x and y axis should be equal length
    x0,x1 = ax.get_xlim()
    y0,y1 = ax.get_ylim()
    ax.set_aspect(abs(x1-x0)/abs(y1-y0))

plt.show()
fig.savefig('plot.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just switch figure size width and height from:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))
```

to:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 20))
```

to use the whole page for your plots.

This will change your plot from:

[image]

to:

[image]