# pandas_ml change confusion matrix image size

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-ml

**How can the size of a `pandas_ml` confusion matrix image with lots of classes be increased so the labels are clearly visible?**

Such an image can be generated in Jupyter like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_ml import ConfusionMatrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import string
%matplotlib inline

classes = string.printable # 100 target classes
df = pd.DataFrame({'true':list(classes*10),
                   'pred':sorted(classes*2)+list(classes*8)
                  })
cm = ConfusionMatrix(df['true'],df['pred'])
cm.plot()
```

[image]

I've tried various suggestions involving [changing figure sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41531042/1717828) and [subfigure sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35881382/1717828), as well as looking for *size* or *width* in the [pandas_ml docs](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pandas-ml/latest/pandas-ml.pdf) but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))

cm.plot(normalized=True, backend="seaborn")

Comment: A little more explanation why this will solve the issue would be nice.

Comment: Confirming this does work, but only when the backend is `seaborn`.  Why is that?